# Array of List<Contact>?

Tags: apex, batch

What syntax is needed to add multiple List of Sobjects to an array?  I have this code currently in a batch class:

```
public List<Contact> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
  List<Contact> contactList1 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey1__c);
  List<Contact> contactList2 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey2__c);
  List<Contact> contactList3 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey3__c);
  return contactList1;
}
```

What I am trying to do is return an array that contains all 3 list.  I know my return type on the method will need to change and the return statement itself, but I am not sure what syntax to use to return I guess what would be an array of Sobjects?

I think I need something more like the below (psuedo-code), but I do not believe this will work as expected:

```
public List<Contact> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
  contactArray = [];
  List<Contact> contactList1 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey1__c);
  List<Contact> contactList2 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey2__c);
  List<Contact> contactList3 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey3__c);
  contactArray.add(contactList1);
  contactArray.add(contactList2);
  contactArray.add(contactList3);
  return contactArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the addAll method instead:

```
  contactArray = new List<Contact>();
  List<Contact> contactList1 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey1__c);
  List<Contact> contactList2 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey2__c);
  List<Contact> contactList3 = ExternalAPI.getDataset(APIKey3__c);
  contactArray.addAll(contactList1);
  contactArray.addAll(contactList2);
  contactArray.addAll(contactList3);
  return contactArray;
```